# (AWS S3) No module named 'storages.backends'; 'storages' is not a package

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting this import error while I'm setting AWS S3 in Django.

When I do 'python3 manage.py collectstatic',

```
  File "/home/jaemin/Desktop/Stylee/workspace/Stylee-API/stylee/stylee/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
ImportError: No module named 'storages.backends'; 'storages' is not a package
```

And this is the utils.py file location.

```
stylee/stylee/utils.py

stylee/stylee/settings/locals.py
```

1) My setting/local.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
    'storages',
]
```

2) Commands to install 'storages'

```
pip3 install boto django-storages-redux
```

3) `python3 manage.py migrate` Output

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, oauth2_provider, profiles, sessions, sites, social_django, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install [`django-storages`](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) you should run:

```
pip3 install django-storages
```

It is recommended to install [`boto3`](https://github.com/boto/boto3):

```
pip3 install boto3
```

On how to use `django-storages` with Amazon S3 see the [docs](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#amazon-s3).